# Client side and server side events not firing simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I have a asp.net button control. My requirement is such that upon clicking the button, it should be disabled and fire a server side event simultaneously. I am disabling the button by

```
onclientclick = "this.disabled = true;"
```

and calling the server side method by

```
onclick = "someserversidemethod"
```

But the thing is that button is getting disabled and not firing the server side event. I want both client side and server side events to fire simultaneously. Please help.

Comment: How about removing the OnClientClick and settings the button to disabled in the serverside-method?

Comment: @Alxandr: Initially I had done so. But the button is inside an update panel and upon clicked makes asynchronous call to a web service. The button gets disabled only after the web service returns. I want it disabled before the service returns so that users cannot click on the button in meantime. That's why I had to go for client side event for disabling the button. Please advise.

Comment: Tried putting 'return true;' after 'this.disabled = true;'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep what you have and also set the property `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`. This will force the button to use the asp.net postback mechanism, rather than the inbuilt browser mechanism.

[See here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)

**EDIT**

Browsers as standard will always submit a form when you click on a `<input type="submit">` control (which is what is rendered to the HTML when you use a `<asp:Button>`). ASP.NET uses this feature to initiate the postback to the server.

The problem you have is that if the button is disabled (like you are doing in your javascript) then the browser will **not** submit the form (i.e. the postback will not happen).

By using the attribute `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` you are telling ASP.NET to ignore the fact that browsers can do the submit themselves, and instead the button should use the JavaScript postback methods provided by ASP.NET (the same methods that are used on `AutoPostback="true"` for things like `<asp:Checkbox>` etc).

The javascript postback ignores the fact that you have just set the control as disabled,meaning the control will be disabled on screen but the postback will still happen.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should go for client side event for disabling the button with UseSubmitBehavior="false" ?

Comment: Correct, keep the client side disabling, but also put the above property on the button. I will add more to my answer to expain it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can u please explain UseSubmitBehavior="false"?